# Expectation of the black ball pairs

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value

Suppose we have total N balls, there are B black balls and W white balls, so that N = B + W. For simplicity, assume both B and W are even numbers. If we randomly pairing them up to form N/2 pairs, assume random variable L is the number of black ball pairs. What is the expectation of L (i.e. black ball pairs)? Is there any known distribution for this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Hint:  use linearity of expectation and indicator variables.

Comment: I was trying to use expectation=P(L=1)*1+P(L=2)*2+...+P(L=B/2)*2. but even one single term is not easy to calculate.

Comment: I think indicator variables are a lot simpler.  You only need to compute the probability that a single pair is $BB$.

Comment: You mean like this?  $X_i = 1$ if pair $i$ is black balls or 0 otherwise. Then $expectation = \sum_i X_i$. The issue is they are not independent, i.e. depends on $X_1$ equals 0 or 1, the formula for $X_2$ will be different.

Comment: Dependence has nothing to do with it.  Expectation is linear regardless of dependence.  That's why this technique is so powerful.

Comment: Right. What I mean is that $X_2$ has different formula when $X_1$ is different. Even more, for the case $X_1=0$, $X_2$ has different values depending on whether the first pair is white-white or white-black pair. i.e. there is not a unique formula for $X_2, X_3,\cdots$. But thanks for your comments, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Once again, that has nothing to do with anything.  The probability that a single pair is $BB$ is just $\frac B{B+W}\times \frac {B-1}{B+W-1}$.  Thus the expected number of $BB$ pairs is $\frac {B+W}2\times \frac B{B+W}\times \frac {B-1}{B+W-1}=\frac {B(B-1)}{2(B+W-1)}$.   The dependence between the $X_i$ simply plays no role at all in the computation.

Answer (score 1):

To summarize the discussion in the comments:

This sort of thing is best handled by indicator variables, exploiting the fact that expectation is linear, regardless of any possible dependence between the variables.

Thus, we let $X_i$ denote the indicator variable for the $i^{th}$ pair, so $X_i=1$ if the $i^{th}$ pair is $BB$ and $X_i=0$ otherwise.  It is easy to see that the probability that the $i^{th}$ pair is $BB$ is $\frac B{B+W}\times\frac {B-1}{B+W-1}$, which is then $E[X_i]$. Note that, of course, this does not depend on $i$.  It follows that the desired result is simply $$E=E\left[ \sum X_i\right]=\sum E\left[X_i\right]=\frac {B+W}2\times \frac B{B+W}\times\frac {B-1}{B+W-1}=\boxed {\frac {B(B-1)}{2(B+W-1)}}$$

and we are done.

Sanity checks:  If $B=0$ this gives $0$, as it should.  If $W=0$ this gives $\frac B2$ as it should.  If $B=W$ and $B$ is large then we expect that roughly $\frac 14$ of the pairs will be $BB$ so the answer should be $\frac B4$ which, in the limit, is confirmed by the formula.  It is a good idea to work a few cases for small $B,W$ by hand just to confirm, but I will leave that as an exercise.

As a significantly harder exercise, you might try to compute the variance of the number of $BB$ pairs.  That can be done along the same lines, but it is harder since variance itself is not linear in the strong way that expectation is.  As a hint, use the fact that the variance of a distribution $X$ is $E\left[X^2\right]-E[X]^2$.

Comment: Let me be more direct - can you please explain why the probability of the $i^{th}$ pair being $BB$ does not depend on $i$? Pairing up the colors as a sequential process would seem to change the probability at each pair depending on the prior pairing. Although the actual probability of $BB$ for each pair is naturally determined by the total number of $B$ and $W$ at the start, why does the actual value remain unchanged? Is it because each pair has the same probability of being the first one picked, in which case $B/(B+W) \times (B-1)/(B+W-1)$ is obvious?

Comment: Each pair is the same as any other pair.  You've just selected two people from the crowd uniformly at random.  Of course, the probability changes if you have information regarding the other pairs, but that is irrelevant to expectation. $E[X+Y]=E[X]+E[Y]$ regardless of any possible dependence between $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: Work it out for a small sample, just to convince yourself.  Say the white balls are $W_1$ and $W_2$ and the black balls are $B_1,B_2$.    Persuade yourself that my claim is correct even though knowing the first pair is $BB$ proves that the second pair can't be.

Comment: And if you still find the thing unintuitive, prove it by induction!  It is easy to verify my formula for the probability if $B,W$ are small, so proceed by induction on the sum $B+W$.  The first pair is easy to analyze and then the rest follow using the induction hypothesis and a little arithmetic.

Comment: So, try the induction.  It's entirely straight forward, though I expect you will be cursing the arithmetic involved, but it's not at all difficult.